# How to declare arrays in mips?

Tags: arrays, stack, mips

i'm confused on how to declare an array into mips.

for example, if you have

```
   int[1000]; //an array in c
```

how would this look like in mips?  Do you have to allocate stack space for the frame?

Comment: You just save the stack pointer to the register where you want to store a pointer to the start of the array, then you increment the stack pointer past the end of your array. Remember to decrement it back when you're done your routine.

Comment: Do you mean like  $addiu $sp, $sp, -1000?